# Can I "write up" employees who are family for calling out on the same days?

Tags: management, sickness, california

I am new to management, I have about 20 employees under me at a supermarket and 3 of them are family members. The family members work staggered shifts and when they have something like a birthday they will all separately ask it off appropriately and it is generally not a problem.

**There have been several occasions however, when it seems one of them will ask for the day off and the others will call out sick. Or they will all call out for a shift. I am wondering if I could write them up for a family call out pattern?** I do not know if there are rules against this in California. I think even if there are rules, I would probably let them all know first before getting them in trouble but I'm curious if anyone has dealt with this?

Comment: I've heard that some diseases can be contagious and can spread around households

Comment: @mgh42, There is also a knock-on effect. If one family member is sick, then maybe the second family member has to take care of them and drive the kids back and forth from school/childcare, or pick up medication at the pharmacy, or drive them to the doctor's, etc.

Comment: To be clear, they are family of eachother but not you?

Comment: *Or they will all call out for a shift.* - Just to be clear, are we talking about sick leave in all instances or is it sometimes some other kind of personal issue like, "Oh, the car broke down and since we carpool none of us can make it?"

Comment: "I would probably let them all know first before getting them in trouble but I'm curious if anyone has dealt with this?"  What kind of issue is this causing that is different from any random 3-4 employees calling out sick or calling out for a shift?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I am wondering if I could write them up for a family call out pattern?

Okay, let's start with laws. Under California laws employees accrue paid sick leave if the are employed longer than 90 days at a rate of 3 days per year (actually, it's an hourly rate, you don't have to wait a full year). For us Europeans, yes, that is correct, it's *three*, I did not miss any zeroes here.

While those three days are meant to be used for

> - The diagnosis, care, or treatment of an existing health condition of, or preventive care for, an employee; and
> - The diagnosis, care, or treatment of an existing health condition of, or preventive care for an employee’s family member.

However, as an employer you are not entitled to any proof about this. You are required to grant them upon request alone.

You cannot discriminate against people because they use their sick leave:

> An employer shall not deny an employee the right to use accrued sick days, discharge, threaten to discharge, demote, suspend, or in any manner discriminate against an employee for using accrued sick days, attempting to exercise the right to use accrued sick days, filing a complaint with the department or alleging a violation of this article, cooperating in an investigation or prosecution of an alleged violation of this article, or opposing any policy or practice or act that is prohibited by this article.

So... that is a flat out **No** to your question if they are using those paid sick days.

However, what if they ran out of this sick leave and use *other* means to call in sick? Well, that would be up to your policies I guess. But what would your policy be? "You were out sick while your brother was attending a birthday party, that is not allowed by our policies." I know you don't have labor laws to speak of in the US, but I would hope that sounds as silly there as it does here.

You can only write up people for what *they* did, not for what their relatives do. If A calls in sick, you have to take that at face value. Whether A's brother took a day off or not is not relevant.

If you have any constraints on sick days, you should make sure they stay inside those. But if they play by the rules then there is little you can do.

You could hire a PI to investigate them. If they *see* them at the birthday party even though they called in sick *for that specific time*, *then* you have grounds for action.

Otherwise... knowing that there is a chance they faked it is worth about as much as knowing there is a chance to win the lottery. Chances aren't relevant in labor law. You have to catch them breaking the rules around taking sick days or you have to catch them lying about being sick. Catch them *personally*, there is no guilt by association here.

Please note that you *can* be out sick in the morning and recover enough to attend a quiet birthday in the evening. That might not even be a lie. I would draw the line at calling in sick for back pain and then helping your buddies with their move in the time you should have been at work though.

Comment: thanks this was a great answer and makes sense to me. I appreciate this and this is helpful

Comment: As a European the concept that you can "run out of sick leave" is, frankly, incomprehensible. As if people were able to control when they get sick or not?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a hill you want to die on.

However, you can **ask** if the family is okay when you get one of these events.  Follow up by asking if they need anything.  This way, if there is nothing shady going on, you'll find out about your employees and may be able to help them.

If there is, they may feel that you are noticing, and stop on there own.  Either way, no writeup needed, and you might earn yourself some good will

Answer (score 3):

Is it a *problem*?

Really, is the fact that they are doing this causing actual difficulty for you?  If it is not?  Let it go.  It's hard to enforce, and any attempt to enforce it is guaranteed to result in significant unhappiness from about one seventh of your total workforce - possibly more.  As a general rule, in any case where you are not suffering materially, it behooves you to be lenient.  It improves morale overall, and it means that when something like this *does* cause a problem, you're in a better position to go to your employees and explain that their behavior is causing issues and work out a way to stop it.

If it *is* causing difficulty, then figure out why.  (It's not the simple fact that they sometimes take coordinated time off - that's happened normally and you've been cool with it.)  Then maybe... talk with them about it.  Pick whichever one of them seems to have the most authority in the group, explain that you've noticed the behavior and you've tried to make allowances for it, but there's this one problem over *here*, and if they could just make *this* little adjustment (like giving you a quiet heads-up in advance so that you can shuffle shifts smoothly, or not doing it too often on the same day of the week, or whatever it is that it would take to not be a problem for you) you can keep everything running smoothly, and it doesn't have to be a *thing*.  I suspect they'll react pretty well to that, especially if they've been good employees otherwise.  If not?  *That's* when you start turning into Bad Boss.

Answer (score 2):

> There have been several occasions however, when it seems one of them will ask for the day off and the others will call out sick.

Well, if you word it that way, you might envisage malicious intent here. However, the more likely possibility seems to be that two of your employees became sick and the remaining one took a day off to help them.

And of course there is "a pattern", if the family members are helpful towards each other.

If your employees are doing everything according to your vacation days and sick leave policies, then everything is fine and you should let them be. If they are breaching the policies, you might have grounds to call them out on that.

Comment: How is it more likely one took a day off to help the others? How would that person know to book leave in advance of two people becoming sick?

Comment: It is not specified in the question that the person takes a day off in advance.

Comment: That's because it's such a standard practice that it doesn't need to be said. With shift work, leave needs to be requested before the shifts are scheduled.